# No se guardan los resultados de una votación usando PHP, MYSQL y JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, guardar

estoy realizando un sistema de votaciones tipo ranking top 10 para un sitio web de radio.

La idea es tener una lista de canciones para votar y esta vaya cambiando de posiciones según la votación, a su vez, que dicho usuario pueda votar una sola vez y estos datos guardarlo en una base de datos MYSQL donde se vayan creando títulos (de las canciones) y posicionando, si el titulo se encuentra en la base que sume otro voto, de lo contrario que cree uno nuevo y le asigne un voto.

El problema radica en que no consigo que los resultados se guarden en la base de datos, ya que al reiniciar la pagina todo vuelve a las posiciones originales y en la base de dato no se registran dichas votaciones.

La tabla esta hecha de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE canciones (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  titulo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  voto INT(6) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
)
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
const botonesVotar = document.querySelectorAll('.votar');

botonesVotar.forEach((boton) => {
  boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const titulo = boton.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    const votos = parseInt(boton.getAttribute('data-votos'));
    $.ajax({
      url: 'guardar_voto.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { titulo: titulo },
      success: (response) => {
        boton.setAttribute('data-votos', votos + 1);
        boton.textContent = `Votar (${votos + 1})`;
        const canciones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).map((li) => ({
          titulo: li.querySelector('.titulo').textContent,
          votos: parseInt(li.querySelector('.votar').getAttribute('data-votos')),
        }));
        const top10 = canciones.sort((a, b) => b.votos - a.votos).slice(0, 10);
        const listaCanciones = document.getElementById('canciones');
        listaCanciones.innerHTML = '';
        top10.forEach((cancion) => {
          const li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerHTML = `
            <span class="titulo">${cancion.titulo}</span>
            <button class="votar" data-votos="${cancion.votos}">Votar (${cancion.votos})</button>
          `;
          listaCanciones.appendChild(li);
        });
      },
      error: (xhr, status, error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.top-10 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.titulo {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.votar {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="voto.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-10">
  <h2>Top 10 Canciones</h2>
  <ul id="canciones">
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 1</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 2</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 3</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 4</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 5</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 6</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 7</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 8</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 9</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="titulo">Canción 10</span>
      <button class="votar" data-votos="0">Votar</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



<script src="voto.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

aqui dejo tambien el archivo php

```
<?php
// Conectar a la base de datos
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
  die('Error al conectar a la base de datos: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Obtener los datos de la solicitud POST
if (isset($_POST['titulo'])) {
  $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['titulo']);

  // Verificar si la canción ya existe en la base de datos
  $sql = "SELECT id, votos FROM canciones WHERE titulo = '$titulo'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Actualizar el número de votos para la canción existente
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $votos = $row['votos'] + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE canciones SET votos = $votos WHERE id = $id";
  } else {
    // Agregar una nueva canción a la base de datos
    $sql = "INSERT INTO canciones (titulo, votos) VALUES ('$titulo', 1)";
  }

  // Ejecutar la consulta SQL
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "La votación se ha registrado correctamente.";
  } else {
    echo "Error al registrar la votación: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
} else {
  echo "Error: el campo 'titulo' no está presente en la solicitud POST.";
}

// Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Si alguien puede indicarme donde estaría el error que no estoy viendo, por favor si me puede guiar un poco.
Desde ya gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP?

Comment: hola, si
sale un error 500 y la url donde se encuentra el archivo php, pero al moverle en el js: `data: { titulo: titulo }` y modificarlo a `data: 'titulo',` ya no tiene el error pero marca que el titulo no existe en el envio POST

Comment: Eso es en el access.log, pero no sale nada más en otro de los logs?

Comment: No me estaria saliendo nada mas, igual en el servidor no tenia habilitado esta opcion, recien lo habilite, me imagino que ahi ya se deberian registrar dichos errores

Comment: Puedes depurar o verificar cómo te llegan los datos usando `var_dump($_POST); die;` o `print_r($_POST); die;`. El resultado se puede ver en el inspector de código de tu navegador o incluso, a veces en la misma vista dependiendo de la configuración de tu proyecto.